# c# HTML Agility Pack Get src image attributes?

Tags: c#

how to get src value from this img class?
I already try, but the result is not work.

This is the element

[image: Element]

This is my script

```
foreach (HtmlNode pict in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//img[@class='c-img-lazy__img']"))
{
    HtmlAttribute pictures = pict.Attributes["src"];
    imageProduct.Add(pictures.Value);
    MessageBox.Show(pictures.Value);
}
```

I want to scrape image product from this website: http://www.lazada.co.id/spinner/?page=1

Comment: How does it not work?  Does the xpath not return the elements?  Do you get an error?  Or are you getting the wrong result and if so what is it?

Comment: Result is null..

Comment: But it's solved, with by use data-js-component-params and get json value